# Problem Help in Studying for Final.

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am reviewing past material and these were two problems that I was stuck on. I want to make sure that I understand them for my final.

Problem 1: An isosceles triangle has two sides of length 10. The angle between is x radians.

Part A: Express the Area A of the triangle as a function of x and find the domain of A(x).

The expression that I got was $\frac{1}{2}(20\sin(x)(10\cos(x))$, would this be the correct expression? If so, how would I go about finding the domain without graphing the function. The correct answer is $[0, \pi]$ based on comments from my teacher.

Problem 2: Angular displacement $\theta$ at time $t$ is given by $\theta (t) =\frac{1}{100} \cos(t-\frac{\pi}{6})$. When is the speed of the pendulum equal to 0?

Am I just supposed to solve the first derivative for 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your area formula is wrong. A simple way to compute the area is to complete the isosceles triangle to form a diamond.

Let us have $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ the sides of equal length, their angle being $\widehat{BAC} = x$. Just considere the point $D$ given by $\vec{AD} = \vec{AB} + \vec{AC}$. The quadrilateral $ABDC$ is a rhombus and its area is simply $AB\times AC\times sin(x)$. And by construction it is twice the area of you original triangle. So the triangle area is just $\frac 1 2 \times 10 \times 10 \times sin(x) = 50 \space sin(x)$

The domain of $x$ is $[0;\pi]$ to have $sin(x) \geq 0$.

---

For the second problem, you are right: the speed of the pendulum is $0$ when the derivative of the angular displacement is $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's a great way at looking at the first problem.